# knitcitations citet gives "Empty reply from server"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rcurl

I am trying to compile an RMarkdown file that includes the `knitcitations` package. I have searched SO for "knitcitations" and [did not find any similar problems to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22knitcitations%22).

My problem is that knitcitations citet gives an error "Empty reply from server".

My smallest reproducible example is

```r
> knitcitations::citet("https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-012088781-1/50004-2")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Empty reply from server
```

I have tried running this in plain R and RStudio and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

`````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:    
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
---

```{r, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitcitations)
library(bibtex)
````

```{r results="asis", echo = FALSE}
citet("10.1016/B978-012088781-1/50004-2")
````
`````

[image]

Good luck in your scientific work ;)

Comment: Thank you. I cannot believe how simple that was.